# Error installing make on Intel Galileo

Tags: makefile, intel-galileo

I am trying to install make on my Intel Galileo using the following command:

```
 opkg install make
```

However, this fails with the following ouput:

```
Installing make (3.82-r3) to root...
Downloading http://iotdk.intel.com/repos/1.0/iotdk/i586/make_3.82-r3_i586.ipk.
Installing libc6 (2.18-r0) to root...
Downloading http://iotdk.intel.com/repos/1.0/iotdk/i586/libc6_2.18-r0_i586.ipk.
Collected errors:
* check_data_file_clashes: Package libc6 wants to install file /lib/libpthread.so.0
        But that file is already provided by package  * libpthread0
* opkg_install_cmd: Cannot install package make.
```

How do I resolve this and get make installed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the latest Intel IoT devkit image. It already brings a great set of developer tools in it, including make.

You can download this image at https://software.intel.com/en-us/iot/hardware/galileo/downloads

The installation manuals can be also found in there.

Comment: Yes, installing the latest image seems to be the easiest solution now. Thanks!